# Returning custom response from AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

How can I configure Amazon API Gateway and AWS Step Functions like this?

Client call an api on api gateway ==> Api Gateway ===> Step Function ===> internally call an lambda  => lambda returns response ==> response is send back to api gateway.

Right now, my Amazon API Gateway instead of invoking AWS Step Functions directly, it invokes a lambda which invokes step function and check its success state, then it returns response to Amazon API Gateway.

Answer (score 3):

With Step Functions Express Workflows, you can directly start a synchronous execution from API Gateway and return the result when it finishes. If your workflow can finish within the API Gateway timeout, this is probably the best option.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/

If using asynchronous executions, the direct API Gateway -> Step Functions integration will not return the final output of the workflow or return the response of a Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

The [StartExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html) API is asynchronous. When you call this API you must call [DescribeExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html) API to get the result.

Thus, [StartSyncExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartSyncExecution.html) API, used with Express Type State Machines, allows you to call Step Functions synchronously. This is limited to up to 5 minutes duration.